# Reloading a java object from disk without creating a new instance?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-adapter

I have an Android app which keeps a persistent log of events in a custom object that extends ArrayList. It is kept in a singleton so that various activities all point to the same one log. The main activity reloads the list in the onResume.

Problem is, when I reload the log, all the UI elements (like the ArrayAdapter) lose the reference and I need to set them up again. It works. But, it seems like a lot of work.

How can I reload the object into the original object's instance so that I don't have to do all that setup again? Using a singleton should make it easier not harder.

I know it's all a problem with pass-by-reference. But I just can't get my head around it.

Java is not my first language... Thanks.

Activity onCreate:

```
dataLog = DataLog.getInstance();
logView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.logView);
dataLogAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.log_row, dataLog);        
logView.setAdapter(dataLogAdapter);
```

Activity onResume:

```
dataLog = Persister.recoverLog(this, "datalog.dat");
dataLogAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.log_row, dataLog);
logView.setAdapter(dataLogAdapter);
```

Persister:

```
public static DataLog recoverLog(Context context, String fileName){
File file = context.getFileStreamPath(fileName);
DataLog obj = new DataLog ();

if(file.exists() && file.length()>0){
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        obj = (DataLog) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return obj;
}
```

DataLog:

```
public class DataLog extends ArrayList<String> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
    public DataLog() {}

    private static DataLog _instance;
    public static DataLog getInstance() {
        if(_instance==null){
            _instance = new DataLog();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public boolean add(String entry) {
        super.add(entry);
        return true;
    }

    public void add(int index, String entry) {
        if (index > 0)
            super.add(index, entry);
        else
            super.add(entry);
    }

    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: It can't be a _problem with pass-by-reference_, Java is pass-by-value. Instead of serializing the object, why don't you just serialize the String entries, one by one?

Comment: A "singleton" could make it easier if you were actually using a singleton. Since you are recreating new instances with the Persister, of course you have to make all of your objects aware of the new reference.

Comment: @JasonC Exactly, I've covered that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datalog isn't a true singleton. If it were, no new reference would be created after it was created the very first time.

This:

```
dataLog = Persister.recoverLog(this, "datalog.dat");
```

should not return a `Datalog` but some internal data `DataLog` uses (an ArrayList of Strings) and  should be called within `DataLog`

Then *only* pass the dataLog instance around. If you ever reassign it you'll have problems. When you reload data log you'll need to reload the structures relying on DataLog's array instance.

Handle reloading your `DataLog` data in `onResume` if necessary, but do it like so:

```
DataLog.getInstance().load();
```

So that your data log is never reassigned. That's the key. DataLog is a wrapper around your data. If DataLog's internal state is changed, no references to `DataLog` are lost.

Here's an example:

```
public class DataLog implements Serializable {
    //internalize this data.
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    //singleton's constructor should be private.
    private DataLog() {}

    private static DataLog _instance;
    public static DataLog getInstance() {
        if(_instance==null){
            _instance = new DataLog();
        }
       return _instance;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getData(){
        //copy this if you're worried about it being modified.
        //DO NOT pass this reference around. Pass a reference to data log, 
        //reload GUI relying  on this reference as needed.
        return data;
    }

    public void load(){
         data = //reload string array from disk.
    }

    public boolean add(String entry) {
        super.add(entry);
        return true;
    }

    public void add(int index, String entry) {
        if (index > 0)
            data.add(index,entry);
        else
           data.add(entry);
   }

    public void clear() {
       data.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful; if you're calling `recoverLog()` "whenever necessary" from `getInstance()`, then that implies `instance_` could change, which is fine, but it means you want to pass `getInstance()` around instead of the instance itself so as not to hold on to old, no-longer-valid references.

Comment: Thanks @JasonC I've explained myself more clearly. Good catch! I wish people got rep for upvotes on comments...

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. So the issue is I can't extend ArrayList but instead contain an ArrayList internally that I can manipulate without affecting external references. I suspected it would be something like that but got lost in the details. Thanks.